# Adding a new queue runner causes program to quit prematurely

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I have a directory with images and another directory with label files (for each image). I am trying to read the image and the labels using queues and read ops.

```
image_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(image_files, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
image_contents = image_reader.read(image_file_queue)[1]

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)
image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [image_size, image_size])

image_batch = tf.train.batch([image],
                             batch_size,
                             num_threads=4,
                             capacity=2 * batch_size,
                             allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

label_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(label_files, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
label_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
label_contents = tf.string_split([label_reader.read(label_file_queue)[1]], delimiter='\n').values

labels = tf.decode_csv(label_contents, [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32)] * 5, field_delim=' ')
label_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(2 * batch_size, [tf.float32])

enqueue_op = label_queue.enqueue([labels])

label_queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(label_queue, enqueue_ops=[enqueue_op] * 2)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(label_queue_runner)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
sess.run(tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()))

threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

However this doesn't work. `coord.should_stop()` returns `True` immediately after this. Commenting `tf.train.add_queue_runner(...)` does work, that is, `image_batch` is computed and I am able to run it through a  CNN. If I don't comment it, `image_batch` seems to be smaller than it should be (`batch_size` is 128, but `image_batch.eval().shape` can be as small as 8). I thought this might be due to insufficient threads, but increasing both `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: Could the part on `image_batch.eval().shape` be as small as 8 be due to `allow_smaller_final_batch=True`?

Comment: Nope there are enough images to read. Also it is not always 8, it keeps changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jkschin is right. The number of image readers is just one, making `num_threads` 64 won't change that. And because `image_batch` can't be filled fast enough, the program stops prematurely when it `image_batch` is dequeued and it is empty.

The right way to solve this problem is to increase the number of image readers (multiple identical subgraphs) as described in [Reading Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data).

```
image_list = [read_image(image_file_dequeue) for _ in range(num_readers)]
image_batch = tf.train.batch_join(image_list, ...)
```